# I want to Go to another Scene after dialogue ends

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm making a 2D game and want to jump from a dialogue scene that is a tutorial for the beginning of the game to a scene where the game starts but I don't know how to achieve that after the dialogue ends. here is the entire script for the scene ( dialogue manager, Dialogue, and Dialogue trigger).

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using TMPro;


public class DialogueManager : MonoBehaviour
{

    public TextMeshProUGUI nameText;
    public TextMeshProUGUI dialogueText;


    private Queue<string> sentences;

    void Start()
    {
        sentences = new Queue<string>();
    }

    public void StartDialogue(Dialogue dialogue)
    {

        nameText.text = dialogue.name;


        sentences.Clear();

        foreach (string sentence in dialogue.sentences)
        {

            sentences.Enqueue(sentence);

        }

        DisplayNextSentence();

    }

    public void DisplayNextSentence()
    {

        if (sentences.Count == 0)
        {

            EndDialogue();
            return;

        }

        string sentence = sentences.Dequeue();

        dialogueText.text = sentence;

    }

    void EndDialogue()
    {

        Debug.Log("End of conversation.");

    }


}
```

And this is the Dialogue Script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

[System.Serializable]
public class Dialogue
{

    public string name;

    [TextArea(3, 10)]
    public string[] sentences;


}
```

And this is the Dialogue Trigger:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class DialogueTrigger : MonoBehaviour
{

    public Dialogue dialogue;

    public void TriggerDialogue()
    {
        FindObjectOfType<DialogueManager>().StartDialogue(dialogue);
    }
}
```

Comment: The tags on SO include valuable usage guidan.ce pertaining to them to help you attract attention from the right sectors for your question.  Hover over the `script` tag and read the usage guidance and act accordingly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`SceneManager.LoadScene`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.SceneManager.LoadScene.html) in your `EndDialogue()` method

```
    void EndDialogue()
    {
        // load new scene here
        Debug.Log("End of conversation.");

    }
```